# Looking for practical examples or books on linear transformations

Tags: differential-geometry, linear-transformations

I am looking for practical examples of linear transformations of 2 and 3 dimensional objects.  I am up to speed on linear algebra but the books I have found so far are more concerned with rigor than with real world examples.  Strang's book has given me the best examples although it is only one page.  What I want to be able to do is to programmatically transform curves and surfaces within my Rhino3D drawing program. I can start by doing some simple things and work up to what I want to study but hoped I could speed up the process if I can find a practical book or website.
Hope this works.  I'm not yet sure about how to respond to people who respond to me but a note said that if I add new material, to edit my post.  So here goes.
One response was a request for a specific example.
Let me first say that for 30+ years I was an electrical engineer and did a fair amound of C and C++ programming including linear algebra for curve fitting.  I am now retired and am an artist blacksmith.  My specific project of the moment is a table whose legs are of an unusual shape having both a curve and a twist in them. This gives them a helicoidal shape over a limited distance. I have worked out the problem practically because I realized that I could form that shape by finding out the correct angle to bend the leg on a particular diameter of pipe.  Problem solved for this project.  However, in general I would like to be able to draw these things.  I have Rhino3D and am pretty good with it and have done some programmatical things using Python scripts.  What I would like to do is to programmatically take a solid shape, say a bar of steel, 5/8" square by 36" long, bend it to a certain curve, and twist it so many degrees.  Why do this programmatically instead of using the drawing tools?  Because I want to be able to adjust amount of bend and twist which is not easy to do using the given drawing tools.  I have found some information about Affine transformations in a book called "Architectural Geometry" but no practical examples.
Thanks to the other responder about the book by Adams.  I'll try to find it.
Well, I think I've got a start.  I went back to Strang's book and studied a bit harder and begin to see my way.  I did a short Python program to translate a point using a matrix.  And Strang also pointed me to a book he used on computer graphics.  Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: Could you be more explicit about what you're looking for? Perhaps a specific example of something you want but haven't been able to find?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but [my linear algebra book with M. Adams](https://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-Geometric-Ted-Shifrin/dp/1429215216) has dozens of examples of geometrically-defined linear transformations and — rather uniquely — a section on computer graphics toward the end.

Comment: You might think it's interesting to read a book about computer graphics. Rotation matrices and camera projection matrices provide good examples of multiplying a matrix by a vector.

Answer (score 1):

You’d probably have more luck with a computer graphics or CAD book (or web site) rather than a linear algebra book.

Some good books are:

[Eberly](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558605940)
[Goldman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005H6YS6Y)
[Faux and Pratt](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470270691)

But they’re a bit expensive, and I expect you’ll find what you need on the internet. Just Google “transformation matrices”. For example, I think [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYB8IZa5AuE) is just brilliant.